# Add list item through visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, custom-list, links-list

I have created a list of links through Visual Studio. Now I want to add items to that list. How can I do it through visual studio itself?

I am using visual studio 2013.

Comment: Can you put some sample code about what you are doing, so we can help you more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you add list using ListInstance then you can add items using ListInstance file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ListInstance Title="LinkList" OnQuickLaunch="TRUE" TemplateType="170" FeatureId="Your feature id" Url="Lists/LinkList" Description="Your description">
    <Data>
      <Rows>
        <Row>
          <Field Name="Title">About</Field>
          <Field Name="Description">Description</Field>
          <Field Name="LinkLocation">http://testlink.com</Field>
          <Field Name="BackgroundImageLocation">
            /sites/Images/tile_about.png</Field>
          <Field Name="LaunchBehavior">New tab</Field>
          <Field Name="Order">2</Field>
        </Row>
      </Rows>
    </Data>
  </ListInstance>  
</Elements>
```

Comment: Is this to be write inside Elements.xml inside ListInstance file? I tried, but getting this error:  The element 'Elements' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/' has invalid child element 'Data' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/'.

Comment: Yes in Elemets.xml of ListInstance file. You can make sure that ListInstance element have child element Data http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms478860(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: The problem was that I created lists as type links. For that data element was not available. Now I created with list. Any way we can make list items as hyperlink.

Comment: How can I add the Images in the Picture Library with the VS2012?