# Add Images with the List/Library Instance

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, custom-list, picture-library

I have to add the default images to the picture library with list instance.

**List Instance as-**

```
<ListInstance Title="Picture Library" OnQuickLaunch="TRUE" TemplateType="109" Url="Lists/Picture Library" Description="My List Instance">
<Data>
<Rows>
<Row>
<Field Name="Photo"></Field>
</Row>
</Rows>
</Data>
</ListInstance>
```

How to add the local image to the **Field**?
I have [this link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85636/add-list-item-through-visual-studio), but here we can add only list items.

Answer (score 0):

Ram,

You need to add a separate module to provisions files in the Picture Library, please follow the instructions in the given blog:

[Copy JS files in Library](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/copy-js-files-to-library-using-module-in-sharepoint-2010/)

The difference will be in the URL you will be giving your picture library URL instead of documents, and the files will be image files not JS files.

If this doesn't work you might need to change the List to a Library, either a document, picture or asset library.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have added it but, still the images are not seen in the new created page library.

Comment: Can you provide your Elements.xml file in the question pls